# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at ColoringScreen/freezeColor()

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, actionscript

hi I am once again asking for pointers on what I did wrong here the code works fine but when I test to play it the output message has this:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at ColoringScreen/freezeColor()
```

here's the code

```
public class ColoringScreen extends MovieClip {
        
        var bitmapDt:BitmapData = new BitmapData (176.8, 176.8);
        var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
        var hexaColor:*;
        var myObject:Object;
        
        public function ColoringScreen() {
            // constructor code
            
            chBackBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backtoMainScreen)
            
            bitmapDt.draw(ColorPickerMc.spectrum);
            ColorPickerMc.spectrum.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, freezeColor);
            
            addEvents(oneMc, twoMc, threeMc, fourMc, fiveMc, sixMc, sevenMc, eightMc, nineMc, tenMc, elevenMc, twelveMc, thirteenMc, fourteenMc, fifteenMc, sixteenMc, seventeenMc, eighteenMc, ninteenMc, twentyMc, twentyoneMc, twentytwoMc, twentythreeMc, twentyfourMc, twentyfiveMc);
        }
        private function addEvents(...objects){
            for(var i:Number=0; i<objects.lenght; i++){
                objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selectObject);
            }
        }
        private function selectObject(e:MouseEvent){
            myObject = e.target;
            ColorPickerMc.spectrum.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, updateColor);
        }
        private function backtoMainScreen(e:MouseEvent) {
            MovieClip(stage.getChildAt(0)).gotoAndStop("Intro");
        }
        
        private function updateColor(e:MouseEvent){
            hexaColor = "0x"+bitmapDt.getPixel(ColorPickerMc.spectrum.mouseX, ColorPickerMc.spectrum.mouseY).toString(16);
            
            ct.color = hexaColor;
            myObject.transform.colorTransform = ct;

        }
        
        private function freezeColor(e:MouseEvent){
            myObject.transform.colorTransform = ct;
            ColorPickerMc.spectrum.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, updateColor);
        }
}
```

I know it's been asked a million times but I'm still scratching my head as to what property or method or what instance am I lacking cuz I checked it and all seem to be in place I named my instances and movie clip symbols all of it are in the same keyframe why does my freezeColor not work anymore? any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Add **trace(myObject);** **trace(myObject.transform);** **trace(ColorPickerMc);** and **trace(ColorPickerMc.spectrum)** before anything else in **freezeColor(...)** and learn which one of them is **null**.

Comment: I still have trouble comprehending the errors, nor how to solve them manually, the error points to myObject.transform.colorTransform = ct; under the private function freezeColor(e:MouseEvent) , I tried understanding how those functions work and any possible fixes for it, and it confused me even more

Comment: I tried to teach you how to **DEBUG** an error. Step by step, not the whole thing at once.